# What changes were made to Boon of Protection? How will it impact Hell/Inferno Monks?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

A lot of monks have been getting by using the Mantra of Healing with the Boon of Protection rune, especially in Hell and Inferno (though it seems to be less effective in Inferno Act II).

[image]
[image]

How has it changed and what is the impact on a Hell/Inferno Monk?  Why is this change necessary?

Comment: Where did you learn that it was changed?  Did that source not tell you what the change was?

Comment: @bwarner http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5271780011 is the source, I don't actively play a monk (yet) so I'm not sure what the implications of the change are.

Comment: Seems like that source not only lists the exact changes but even the reason behind the change.

Comment: @bwarner The lack of examples didn't make it clear for someone who doesn't actively play a monk build (heck even my primary isn't at L42 yet anyway even if it was a monk).  Additionally if someone finds a build that relies on the skill and then doesn't understand why it isn't working well for them, I figured this would help explain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rune is being changed to be [capped at the amount of healing given by Mantra of Healing's activated ability.](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5271780011#1) For example, using the stats in the given screenshots, it would be a 3721 damage shield.

Prior to this change you could potentially have a significantly more powerful damage shield  - builds using it commonly have over 50k HP - and it's an extremely spammable ability. Its impact was most noticable in Hell and early Inferno, though later Inferno acts are horrifyingly lethal and hateful of melee classes even with this ability.

Comment: In the past the damage shield could have been for a much higher amount is the take home message?

Comment: Potentially significantly so - builds using it commonly have over 50k HP - and it's an extremely spammable ability. Its impact was most noticable in Hell and early Inferno, as later Inferno acts are horrifyingly lethal and hateful of melee classes even with this ability.

Comment: Now that makes it perfectly clear.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the Blizzard rep's [post yesterday](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5271780011), Blizzard's latest [Hotfix Notes](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/blog/5825330/Diablo_III_Hotfixes_-_May_Updated_52312-5_23_2012) go into further detail:

> Mantra of Healing
>
> Mantra of Healing will now correctly provide only two times the base healing effect for the first 3 seconds after activation, down from four times the base healing effect (tooltip will still show the old value)
>
> Skill Rune - Boon of Protection
>
> A maximum absorption amount has been set to 1000 Life.  This skill will be redesigned in an upcoming patch.